# Swift 5 - Trying to Add Drag & Drop to Reorder my tableView but getting an error when using the tableView moveRowAt function

Tags: arrays, swift, drag-and-drop

I have no problem when using a generic string array to perform drag & drop in a tableView using this function:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
  categories.swapAt(sourceIndexPath.row, destinationIndexPath.row)
  tableView.reloadData()
}
```

But when I use my array "categories" described by the following Category class I get an error:
Value of type 'Results?' has no member 'swapAt'.
This class is a parent class to the "items" child class. Both classes follow:

```
class Category: Object { 
  @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
  @objc dynamic var color: String = ""
  let items = List<Item>() //This is a Realm DB requirement
} 

class Item: Object {
  @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
  @objc dynamic var done: Bool = false
  @objc dynamic var dateCreated: Date?
  @objc dynamic var dueDate: Date?
  @objc dynamic var priority: String?
  var parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: Category.self, property: "items") 
//The line above is a Realm DB requirement
}
```

Both classes above end with linking objects required by Realm DB.
What change can I make to be able to use the ".swapAt" function to move the dragged item to its new position?

Everything else in the app works fine. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `categories`?

Comment: `let realm = try! Realm()    
var categories: Results<Category>?` categories is a string array that contains the data displayed in my tableViewController that I am trying to implement drag & drop on. It is typed as Results<Category> in order to conform to the Realm DB linking parents / children. Category is a parent.